# Segmentation Fault for large arrays defined in a class

Tags: arrays, segmentation-fault

I am trying to program a 3-D vector field in a 2-D surface.
I defined a class for it, along with several functions.

Everything works fine as long as Lx*Ly stays under a certain value.

If I try to define a larger array it gives me a segmentation fault.

This is the very simple code:

```
class CampVec{

public:
    double R[Lx][Ly][3]; //this makes space for the 3 components of the vector
                         //for each point in a Lx*Ly grid.
};
```

From what I understand, the problem is the CampVec objects are stored in the stack instead of the heap, but I haven't been able to find how to fix this when the definitions are inside a class.

I bet this isn't really complicated, so sorry if this is a stupid question, I sincerely have searched and tried several things to no avail.

Best wishes and thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to do it on the stack?
The internals of a vector are taken from the heap and can be cast to look like your array:

```
#include <vector>
class CampVec{
    std::vector<double> _R; 
public:
    typedef double __AT[Lx][Ly][3];
    __AT &R;
    CampVec():_R(Lx*Ly*3),R( reinterpret_cast<__AT&>(&_R[0]) ){} // ctor
};
```

You could also try to find what compiler options your compiler uses to increase the stack size, but why does it have to be on a stack?

Comment: Oh, no; from what I understand they are in the stack now. I would rather have them on the heap. (That would solve my problem, right?)